# Unable to remove the class for the previous selected Item in Menu Bar

Tags: jquery

When a Item is selected under the Menu Bar .
I am adding a class to that Item named active .

For the first time this is working Fine .

Incase if we select a different element under the Menu , how to remove the class for the previously selected Item ?

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7ACwU/1/

I tried to solve this by

```
$(document).on("click", "#swiper-wrapper li", function() {
     var previousselected = '';
    if(previousselected!='')
    {
        $('#previousselected').removeClass(active);
    }

    var selectedeleemnt = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("active");
     previousselected = selectedeleemnt ;
});
```

But i couldn't able to remove the class for the previus ones .

Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 1):

What is #prevoiusselected?
I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ACwU/4/):

```
$(document).on("click", "#swiper-wrapper li", function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Damn it, @Bhushan Kawadkar was faster.

Comment: @Preethi Jain, well, if it works, would you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

`active` is a class make it in quotes

```
$('#previousselected').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : remove `"active"` class from all li which are having `class="active"`

```
$(document).on("click", "#swiper-wrapper li", function() {

    // remove class from previously active li
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    // add active class to clicked li
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ACwU/3/)**